# Как создать новую строку в уже имеющимся фрейме данных с новыми значениями?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Загружаю данные из словаря, где значения все время меняются.

Вот код в цикле:

```
tempo = time.time() + 1000000000
while time.time() < tempo:
    symbol_info = mt5.symbol_info('@DD')
    if symbol_info != None:
        symbol_info_dict = mt5.symbol_info('@DD')._asdict()
        df = pd.DataFrame([symbol_info_dict])
        print(df)
```

Программа выводит колонки по ключам и их значения в строку. Но при каждом запросе цикла и изменения значений опять создаются названия колонок и новые значения.

Как создать новую строку в уже имеющимся фрейме данных с новыми значениями?

Comment: Вас попросили  привести в вопросе воспроизводимый пример данных. У вас возникли  какие-то сложности с этим, если да, то какие?

Answer (score 2):

Пример:

Исходный фрейм:

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3], "b":[11,12,13], "c":[-1,-2,-3]})

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   a   b  c
0  1  11 -1
1  2  12 -2
2  3  13 -3
```

добавляем одну строку

```
In [6]: df.loc[len(df)] = [4, 14, -4]
```

результат:

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
   a   b  c
0  1  11 -1
1  2  12 -2
2  3  13 -3
3  4  14 -4
```

Comment: супер, ваш вариант работает. но у меня другой случай. сами значения меняются, а ключи нет.... вот не знаю как быть..

Comment: @xxxHEKETOSxxx, можете привести в вопросе __воспроизводимый__ пример данных? Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)