# Как создать фрейм данных и записать новую строку в него?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, словари, dict

Получаю данные и обрабатываю их. Данные приходят в виде словаря, где ключ это заголовок столбца, а значение - строки в нем. Есть скрипт, который делает запросы и получает в ответ новые данные, теже ключи но новые значения.

Проблема в том, что при каждом получении ответа, фрейм данных обновляет или перезаписывает одну единственную строку, не добавляя в него новую строку.

Что можно сделать, чтобы добавлялись во фрейм данных новые строки при получении ответа? И как реализовать все это?

Мой код :

```
tempo = time.time() + 1000000000
while time.time() < tempo:
    symbol_info = mt5.symbol_info('@CLE')
    if symbol_info != None:
        symbol_info_dict = mt5.symbol_info('@CLE')._asdict()
        df = pd.DataFrame([symbol_info_dict])
```

Вывод :

```
[1 rows x 96 columns]
   custom  chart_mode  select  visible  ...  isin  name  page                   path
0   False           1    True     True  ...        @CLE        Exchange-Futures\@CLE
```

Ну а вообще пытаюсь все это сделать для сбора данных. Далее, хочу поставить это все на запись для последующего анализа. Если у кого есть варианты, или опыт в записи большого кол-ва данных, буду рад видеть ваш код и перинять ваш опыт.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Ну я уже говорю о том, что никто, кто не имеет счастья работать с mt5 проверить и подправить ваш код не может. Ну да ладно. А вот вопрос  -  покажите хоть строку, где вы думаете, что ДОБАВЛЯЕТЕ данные к существующему DataFrame?

Comment: `"данные приходят в виде словаря, где ключ это заголовок столбца, а значение - строки в нем."` - данные приходят по одной строке или строк может быть больше? Т.е. может ли быть строк в ключе больше одной?

Comment: В цикле все прекрасно описанно... особенно там видно как данные приходят в словаре.

Comment: Настоятельно советую вам научиться создавать __воспроизводимые__ примеры данных в вопросах. В вашем случае достаточно было привести примеры двух-трех небольших словарей с одинаковой структурой и показать что именно вы хотите из них получить... Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы добавить к одному фрейму другой с таким же набором столбцов можно воспользоваться:

1. [df1 = df1.append(df2)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)
2. [df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2])](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

NOTE: объединение фреймов достаточно медленная операция! Поэтому разработчики Pandas рекомендуют собирать массив данных и по окончанию сбора создавать DataFrame из собранных данных. Такой подход будет быстрее работать и будет расходовать меньше памяти (при правильной реализации).

[Как добавить одну строку к DataFrame](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219600/211923)

> Ну а вообще пытаюсь все это сделать для сбора данных, далее хочу
> поставить это все на запись для последующего анализа. Если у кого есть
> варианты, или опыт в записи большого кол-ва данных, буду рад видеть
> ваш код и принять опыт от вас.

Для хранения большого кол-ва данных придумали базы данных.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

db_filename = "/tmp/db.sqlite"

row_count = 0
batch_size = 10000
data = []

db_conn = sqlite3.connect(db_filename)

while time.time() < tempo:
    symbol_info = mt5.symbol_info('@CLE')
    if symbol_info:        
        data.append(symbol_info._asdict())
        row_count += 1
        if row_count == batch_size:
            df = pd.DataFrame(data)
            df.to_sql("data", db_conn, if_exists="append")
            row_count = 0
            data = []
```

Comment: на скольлко я понял нужно в самом начале создать свой df? И уже добавлять в него?

Comment: Для объединения необходимо иметь как минимум два фрейма